# Android use namespace as prefix for attributes in library

Tags: android, namespaces, prefix

I am trying to implement the ActionBar through the support library, v7. Because I want to support the app for Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

I read in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html following:
"Using XML attributes from the support library
Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library."

My question is how do I use my own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library?

Step by step explanation please!
//Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example of a menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     xmlns:whatever="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@id/wims_ab_done"
        android:icon="@drawable/white_check_mark"
        android:title="@string/save"
        whatever:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@id/wims_ab_items_remove"
        android:icon="@drawable/wims_remove"        
        android:title="@string/remove"
        whatever:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

The whole philosophy is to have `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` in the namespace attribute in root `menu`. It doesn't matter what is the namespace identifier as long as it's valid and is used as such when using `showAsAction` attributes. Does this answer your question?

Comment: In this specific case what happends when I use "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"? How does it complement compared to the showAsAction that is built-in in 3.0 and abow.Thanks for your quick answer! :)

Comment: For short: It's a matter of avoiding namespace collision that compatibility package makes sure sure you don't bump into.

Comment: I get the error: Gradle: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.example', What am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using Gradle, but good old Eclipse ADT. Except googling for: `"Gradle": No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction'` I am not able to help you.

Comment: @gunar Is it possible to setup things so that custom attributes defined in support library do not require any prefix? Or is it mandatory to define xmlns in any way?