# ActionBar ShowActions & v7 compat

Tags: android, eclipse, namespaces

I've read a lot of the answers online about how I'm required to add my own namespace in order to get the action bar working when the v7 compatibility library is used. This link describes the answer this solution:

[Android use namespace as prefix for attributes in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514305/android-use-namespace-as-prefix-for-attributes-in-library)

I have an additional question about how this is the case? How does adding a library remove the ShowActions attribute from the android namespace? Does it override some method within the newest library (since my target sdk is 4.~) so that showactions isn't supported within the default android namespace? Why would it do this?

Comment: your min sdk is below 11?

Comment: in this case, it's not. However, the ADT adds the v7 compat anyways. Anyways, my question really isn't what's happening but how can a library cause this under the hood.

Comment: read Using XML attributes from the support library  at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: i guess more specifically I'm wondering why this workaround is required when running my app on a 4.4 phone. shouldn't it just fail to work on a lower end device if I don't apply this fix?

Comment: you don't need a workaround if you don't support below 11 you can use the attribute available in the android name space. Why you need your own attribute below 11 cause it is not available in the android framework on older devices. Also can get rid of support library if you don't need one.

Comment: But that's not true. Without the workaround it doesn't work on my 4.4 device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59391/discussion-between-impguard-and-raghunandan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does adding a library remove the ShowActions attribute from the android namespace?

It doesn't, it's simply that the `ActionBar` and related XML attributes don't exist in the runtime libraries of older versions of Android.

The compatibility libraries are 'static' libraries which are packaged with your APK file when you build your app so that older versions of Android can use the various classes etc. In order to use certain XML attributes, however, as they aren't available in the older Android versions, you have to use the namespace workaround.

For example, if you look at [Adding Action Items](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) you see the following XML file...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

Notice the two attributes for `xmlns:` at the top - one for `android` and one for `yourapp`. Each time you specify an attribute such as `android:icon=`, it uses the `xmlns:android=` namespace but in order to find the support library attributes, it needs to use the second namespace, i.e., `xmlns:yourapp=`. This is why you then prefix attributes with `yourapp:` such as `yourapp:showAsAction=`. In reality you don't even need to use your own namespace and it could be anything you choose (even 'yourapp').

Comment: Hmm, so I set my project to target a min sdk of 11, but Eclipse includes the library anyways. What I've figured is that the android runtime does the parsing of the XML to figure out how to display an activity.

What I don't get is why my action items don't show up as a button when I run the simple demo app on my phone, which is on 4.4. Does adding this library do something to the android runtime when it tries to display this activity?

Comment: Yes, the static libraries override the runtime libraries - there's no mechanism to use the runtime libraries for later versions and the static libraries for earlier versions. If you use the static compatibility libraries, that's all that will be used.

Comment: Aha, that was the answer I was looking for. Interesting that this is how they implemented their runtime libraries. Thanks!

Comment: @ImpGuard : Glad to help. I think the reason it's done this way is to simplify things. At build time it's not possible to tell what Android API will be used when the app is running. As a result all the 'hooks' into the static libraries are permanent.

Comment: interesting. Is there a good place to look into these details behind the compilation/behind the scene processes for android apps?

Comment: @ImpGuard : You'd have to find the source for the Build Tools (something I've never sought out). My guess is they *could* allow dynamic use of the runtime libraries by checking version or fail-over to the static libraries if the API version needs them. But if you build for lower API versions, the static libraries would need to be packaged anyway and performing dynamic checks would only add bloat to the code so why not use the static libraries?