# Custom namespace Support Library ActionBar?

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

I'm an Android beginner programmer and I've found a few others question about this topic, but, unfortunately, they weren't what I was searching for :(.
Android Developers says:

> "If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on
>   versions as low as Android 2.1, the showAsAction attribute is not
>   available from the android: namespace. Instead this attribute is
>   provided by the Support Library and you must define your own XML
>   namespace and use that namespace as the attribute prefix. (A custom
>   XML namespace should be based on your app name, but it can be any name
>   you want and is only accessible within the scope of the file in which
>   you declare it.)"

I think a namespace is a group of names of elements and attributes univocally identified by an identifier (correct me if I'm wrong please). So am I forced to use compulsorily "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" as the namespace URI? Is it a container, for instance, of the showAsAction attribute?
I'd like you to answer these two questions.
Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english!!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514305/android-use-namespace-as-prefix-for-attributes-in-library) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are obligated to use that URI, so you can access the `showAsAction` attribute, in pre-Android API 11.

Using this URI, you will have access to the Support Library custom attribute `showAsAction`, using a custom namespace.

This URI is replaced with the app specific one at build time.